# aurelia-bundler gulp.js can't be found

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

This is the content of my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');

var config = {  
  force: true,
  packagePath: '.',
  bundles: {
    "dist/app-build": {
      includes: [
        'Main.js',
      ],
      excludes:[
          "gulpfile.js",
      ],
      options: {
        inject: true,
        minify: true
      }
    },
    "dist/aurelia": {
      includes: [
        'aurelia-bootstrapper',
        'aurelia-fetch-client',
        'aurelia-router',
        'aurelia-animator-css',
        'github:aurelia/templating-binding',
        'github:aurelia/templating-resources',
        'github:aurelia/templating-router',
        'github:aurelia/loader-default',
        'github:aurelia/history-browser',
        'github:aurelia/logging-console'
      ],
      options: {
        inject: true,
        minify: true
      }
    }
  }
};

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    console.log("ok");  
 return bundler.bundle(config);
});
```

When I run gulp bundle the following error occurs:

> [08:08:54] 'bundle' errored after 536 ms [08:08:54] Error on fetch for
>   gulp.js at file:///C:/myapp/gulp.js
>           Loading gulpfile.js
>           Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myapp\gulp.js'
>       at Error (native)

I wounder why he is searching for gulp.js in the root Directory of the project and not inside the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing this file does is attempt to require 'gulp' - have you done an `npm install` first?

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the problem solved by deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install again